Ignoring type errors in a prepack script
https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts says

For instance, a typical prepack script would call Babel or TypeScript on the source directory to turn .ts files into .js files.

and

Because it's only called on prepublish, the prepublish hook shouldn't have side effects. In particular don't transpile the package sources in prepublish, as people consuming directly your repository (such as through the git: protocol) wouldn't be able to use your project. Instead, use prepack.

As it happens, our package currently does exactly the wrong thing and I want to allow using it through git:. We already have a build NPS script, so it would seem I just need to add
"prepack": "nps build",

to scripts (or directly "tsc --project packages/node-renderer/src"). My issue is that when used through git:, it seems devDependencies of my package don't get installed (which makes sense), and the prepack script will produce errors because of missing @types packages, etc.
How can I fix the script to ignore any such errors (but preferably still fail errors not caused by such a problem)? Is there a better option than
"prepack": "nps build &> /dev/null || true"

or || [ -f <a file that should be built> ]?
